# Creating a sessions object for a Java REST client

Tags: java, session, design-patterns, access-token

I am working on a java client that makes REST aPI alls to an API server . Every time it requests an API it authenticates itself with an auth token.

I want to wrap this information in a sessions object to have it handy for objects making RESt calls

```
public class MySession {
    public static String api_endpoint ;
    public static String username ;
    public static String password ;




    public MySession(String api_endpoint, 
            String auth_endpoint, S
            String username, String password,) {

        this.api_endpoint = api_endpoint;
        this.auth_endpoint = auth_endpoint;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;



    }



    public String getAuthToken()  {
        // use the mySession.user and mySession.pass to get the auth token
        return authToken;

    }


}



public class MyOtherClass {

MySession mysession;

public (MySession msession) {
this.mysession = msession;
}

public void makeRestCall() {

String token = msession.getAuthToken();
// use token and make REST call
}
```

Is this the right way to write the getAuthToken method? Is there any flaw in my design?

Comment: Session is not good way while implementing REST. it is always advisable to keep it stateless as it works on HTTP methods. You can use different authentication techniques like oauth, jwt token, etc.

Comment: Hi Suyash, can you talk to an example of how to maintain this information required for each REST action?